# scatterplot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a following data :

```
251
63
0
-109
15
0
0
139
-182
0
94
-110
0
-155
-103
39
-106
0
-225
-99
89
-128
145
122
0
0
-58
158
-115
-115
0
0
141
-33
-148
-41
55
0
77
92
-174
91
-82
130
18
119
0
128
103
35
-119
0
-184
88
83
-35
-164
129
0
-94
-102
-129
78
-58
44
0
90
-262
-217
0
0
-157
0
0
-66
0
0
76
0
36
-135
0
0
0
50
0
0
55
0
0
0
0
0
-123
0
-92
-151
-119
0
0
0
57
3
0
151
0
0
-102
-123
75
-88
0
147
2
0
0
0
-89
0
0
-68
159
-63
86
-192
114
-103
0
-84
97
0
0
18
0
0
-103
0
0
-154
-64
0
-151
9
35
0
-140
0
-122
-149
-209
0
-98
0
107
0
-104
140
70
0
96
0
-37
0
-205
80
0
-93
-68
-101
12
-141
-92
0
0
0
88
0
0
0
0
12
-133
0
0
0
56
0
0
226
0
101
-124
236
-30
0
-143
73
-176
193
0
29
67
0
149
65
0
125
65
-82
-126
132
0
84
-103
0
9
37
91
-111
-125
-53
-194
200
-63
80
-97
-86
163
0
0
0
60
0
132
0
-162
0
0
0
98
68
0
40
0
0
87
-93
77
-127
0
13
-148
0
88
202
0
-132
0
-99
0
-116
0
-162
0
0
0
0
-36
0
0
0
0
0
-75
0
100
100
48
-148
-44
0
0
27
-111
144
-156
0
0
-20
-97
-187
56
-148
0
-34
0
0
-163
0
6
6
208
110
-102
-64
93
0
0
116
-105
-111
80
-126
-203
-86
0
0
1
-96
0
0
0
0
187
0
-76
34
-67
96
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
90
72
126
-71
-109
0
124
0
0
0
0
0
16
65
-190
0
0
0
43
93
-67
-87
80
154
0
-210
80
203
-70
-154
0
0
-64
-84
-102
0
-141
0
0
-141
42
-84
0
89
0
0
-151
-97
-22
-100
0
140
-155
0
0
-191
83
130
207
-48
-92
29
0
0
0
0
-147
0
-72
```

I would like to generate a plot like this in R (the one below is generated in excel). Any directions? I tried, plot command but it doesn't generate the one I like to.
[image]

The data is mapped (in figure generated from excel)around the "0" value on y axis and x axis can be treated as row numbers or something like that.

Kindly help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: could anyone explain, the down vote. I didn't find any solution to generate such a graph with the given dataset. That is why I posted it here.

Comment: Part of it is likely that your question is not reproducible, part of it is that questions like this have been asked here many times, and part of is it that for a scatter plot, you need data for two columns (for the x and y axis, respectively) and you only provided one vector

Comment: @tifu there's nothing in R, Stackoverflow, or statistics that says data must be in two columns, despite Tidyverse best practice. R easily handles single vectors. The question may however be a duplicate..

Comment: @geothery sure, but we need to know how OP wants to map the data to the axes then, no? on further inspection, your solution apparently is what OP requested (values on y, sequence on x), but that should have been more clearly stated.

Comment: @geotheory & tifu  please see the updated question.As far as being duplicate is concern. I will be pleasantly surprised, if you can find one such question in stackoverflow. Anyway, I am looking for a solution to this problem rather winning an argument. I will be happy to lose this argument and get the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First put the data in a more usable format:

```
y <- c(0, -99, 0, -116, 0, -162, 0, 0, 0, 0, -36, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -75,
 0, 100, 100, 48, -148, -44, 0, 0, 27, -111, 144, -156, 0, 0,
-20, -97, -187, 56, -148, 0, -34, 0, 0, -163, 0, 6, 6, 208, 110,
-102, -64, 93, 0, 0, 116, -105, -111, 80, -126, -203, -86, 0, 0, 
1, -96, 0, 0, 0, 0, 187, 0, -76, 34, -67, 96, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 90, 72, 126, -71, -109, 0, 124, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 65, -190,
0, 0, 0, 43, 93, -67, -87, 80, 154, 0, -210, 80, 203, -70, -154,
0, 0, -64, -84, -102, 0, -141, 0, 0, -141, 42, -84, 0, 89, 0, 
0, -151, -97, -22, -100, 0, 140, -155, 0, 0, -191, 83, 130,
207, -48, -92, 29, 0, 0, 0, 0, -147, 0, -72)
```

Now a basic plot is just

```
plot(y)
```

But that is not very similar to your example so let's add.

```
plot(NA, xlab="", ylab="", ylim=c(-300, 300), xlim=c(0, 150), las=1)
grid(lty=1)
points(y, pch=16, col="blue")
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
d0 = "
1
2
3"

d = read.table(text = d0, header=F)
ggplot(d, aes(seq_along(V1), V1)) + geom_point()
```

Alternatively `plot(d[,1])` will work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put values to x & y
2. Do x-y plot

   `x <- c(251, 63, 0, -109, 15, 0, 0) 
   y <- c(139, -182, 0, 94, -110, 0, -155)
   plot(x, y)`